# Android: Preventing search dialog being dismissed after search.

Tags: java, android, search, dialog

I want a search that stays on the current activity and just filters the data within it. So far I've tried the search widget but some issues with it. (can't get the onDismissListener to work, or customise the view very easily, I can get around these but I would prefer not to rely on those at the momemnt.)

Alternatively I would like to use the "Search Dialog" however, when the search query has been entered the dialog then disappears, which is not ideal behaviour since I want the user to be able to dismiss the search when ready to return to the view's previous state (with its data not filled)

I've tried multiple ways to do this now and have had no luck.

Any ideas?

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

Far as I can tell there seems to be no way to do this.

To get around this and search widget not response to its on close listener, I extended SearchView and implemented my own listener and then implemented another listener in the main class.